# update variable from 7.1 to 7.2 : got error message "The form has become outdated"

Tags: 7, updating, i18n-l10n

Got D7 multilingual configuration with many modules, from which i18n...

Trying to update variable from 7.1 to 7.2 version, following http://drupal.org/node/1660798 #1 tutorial (I also tried other methods explained in other nodes like http://drupal.org/node/1670274 ).

After clearing cache (twice !), replacing old i18n and variable folders with the new ones, I try to run update.php. Nothing happens, I mean reloading same page... I try then to put website into maintenance mode.

After submitting maintenance mode form, got error message "The form has become outdated. Copy any unsaved work in the form below and then reload this page."
So I tried to put first into maintenance mode, **before** replacing folders. But then back to the same story : update.php reloads its page so I have to check again if I'm still into maintenance mode : BUT I'm not anymore...!

I guess what may happen is that changing variable folder generates the following mistake : Drupal doesn't read correctly its database variables, so doesn't see any more it is into maintenance mode ?

So who from the egg or hen comes first ? How could I manage that and stop eating aspirin ? Thanks a lot for sharing experience

Comment: All right, as it occurs sometimes, you search two nights, and one hour after posting a question you find the solution somewhere ( http://drupal.org/node/1666670 #7 ). Just had to update from i18n 1.4 to 1.5 and variable 1.1 to 1.2, then updating to variable 2.1 and i18n 1.7 versions becomes as simple as boiling an egg !!! Many people were searching the same last days, I hope it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer the question :

for people who don't manage to update simultaneously variable and i18n to get variable 2.1 & i18n 1.7 :

even if unusual, you have to **update first** from your current version (i.e i18n 1.4  and variable 1.1 ) **to i18n 1.5 and variable 1.2**, only after that you'll be able to update to variable 2.1 and i18n 1.7 versions.

Always following same steps :

- clear cache
- replace modules folders with the new version
- run update.php